# MainActivity destroys itself between Splash Screen LifeCycle

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have an SplashScreen and a MainActivity, when tha app launchs it displays the Splash Screen (3 secs delay) then the MainActivity, but when I click a BarNotification of mi App (outside of the App) the Splash Screen Displays(3 seconds delay) and the App Crashes, in LogCat he MainActivity Destroys itself between the Splash Screen Intent LifeCycle. (at lines 29,30 [logcat](http://pastebin.com/NTViyZgJ))

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="splash screen"
            android:id="@+id/splash"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Why I'm not able to Launch correctly the App through the Bar Notificaction?**

Here is some code:

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;

    public MainActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        log.debug("onCreate(): " + savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.startSomeMobileCore(this);
        MyApplication.startSomeMobileNotifier(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        onNewIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        log.debug("onStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        this.wasRestarted = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.receivedIntent = false;
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.receivedIntent = false;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        log.debug("onNewIntent(): " + intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if(intent == null) {
            log.warn("Received null intent, will ignore");
        }

        if ("OK".equals(authCode)) {


            if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null &&
                ("content".equals(intent.getData().getScheme()) || 
                "http".equals(intent.getData().getScheme()))) {
                log.debug("intent.getData() :" + intent.getData() + "; intent.getData().getScheme() : " + intent.getData().getScheme());
                String requestedPath;
                if ("http".equals(intent.getData().getScheme())) {
                    requestedPath = URLDecoder.decode(intent.getData().toString());
                } else {
                    requestedPath = intent.getData().getPath();
                }
                showResource(requestedPath);
            } else {
                log.debug("Intent without data -> go to entry page after splash screen");
         showResource(Configuration.properties.getProperty(""));
            }
        } else {
            Intent errorIntent = new Intent(this, ErrorIntent.class);
            startActivity(errorIntent);
            // finish actual activity
            finish();
        }

        log.debug("Show splash screen");
        Intent intentSplash = new Intent(this, SplashIntent.class);
        startActivity(intentSplash);
    }

    void showResource(String resourceToShow) {
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(resourceToShow);
    }
}
```

SplashIntent.java

```
public class SplashIntent extends Activity {
    // Time splash screen should be shown (in ms)
    private static final int splashTime = 3000;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SplashIntent.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        log.debug("SplashIntent: onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 log.debug("SplashIntent: killing splash");
                 finish();
             }
        }, splashTime);

    }
}
```

[logcat](http://pastebin.com/NTViyZgJ)

Hope you guys can help me with this... I'm really out of ideas at this point

Comment: Stack trace would be helpful too. EDIT: Sorry, I just realized you added the link.

Comment: don't finish the splashActivity in run(), rather  Use intent to move to MainActivity() in run() method

Comment: have you declared your main activity global activity ?

Comment: When I move from SplashIntent to Main Activity I get a cycle where SplashINtent executes n times and never reach MainActivity @kishorepatel

Comment: It's already a Global Activity. @HammadTariqSahi

Comment: Try this code: `code` mSplashThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(2000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, SlideMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start(); `code`

Comment: If the above code doesn't work. Then please comment the Intent to SplashActivity in onNewIntent(Intent intent) method, because I think you are in an **infinite loop**

Comment: I did put that code on my SplashIntent and yes, you are right I'm in infinite loop indeed, but with that fix it doesn't displaying the splash screen.. never created in LogCat. I have a blank screen for a seconds before MainActivity, but I need that Blank Screen be my Splash Screen @kishorepatel

Comment: offtopic: why you use this way: SplashIntent extends Activity?
Activity is like a controller. Intent is like an Event. They have different roles. (imho) In my case i've start activity from notification with intent (use class name of activity).

Comment: @kishorepatel you don't need a thread to start an activity from notification ;)

Comment: @drdrej  thread is for wait(2000), not for Intent to start an activity

Comment: @kishorepatel oops, was to fast :)

Comment: @drdrej It's alright :-) . Even I do make such mistakes a lot in order to quickly reply or answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your `SplashIntent` class

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {       
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                SplashIntent.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashIntent.this.finish();
            },splashTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get a cycle in Splash, so never reach the MainActivity.